# Adjust Column Spacing Between Desktop and Mobile

Tags: html, css

I'm using Cargo Collective to build a personal website. I currently have an info page with my resume where on desktop the two columns are close to each other but on mobile I want them spaced out. Screenshots are attached. You can see in the screenshots how crowded the mobile version gets. I'm a novice when it comes to custom coding these things so any help would be awesome.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmWTw.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Ykr.png)

I've tried googling a few things with no luck so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see where the problem is.
In a lot of cases, you can solve using flex wrap. this is an example:

```js
/* Basic styling for the flex container */
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around; /* Adjust as needed */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Allow items to wrap to the next line */
}

/* Styling for the flex items */
.item {
  flex: 1 1 200px; /* Flex properties (flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis) */
}

/* Media query for responsiveness */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .flex-container {
    justify-content: center; /* Change the alignment for smaller screens */
  }

  .item {
    flex-basis: 45%; /* Adjust the size of items for smaller screens */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

It would help if you can share some code.
I hope this helps :)

Comment: Refrain from providing an answer if the question is unclear or missing information. Instead either comment on the question, asking the asker to provide more information, or vote to close the question. ("Needs details or clarity" or "Needs debugging details" would be appropriate in this case.)

Comment: I know @Ouroborus but I have provided an example of how he can achieve it without provides the code in case he doesn't want to.

Comment: "doesn't want to" provide code isn't really an option here. Part of an asker's responsibility is to provide a minimal, reproducible example illustrating the issue.

Comment: since I'm new here and new to this whole world, I wasn't aware I needed to provide code @Ouroborus. What would be most helpful? I can provide a link to my website for you to inspect the code? davidroseberry.co

Comment: @DavidRoseberry As I said: A minimal, reproducible example illustrating the issue